# IPython HTML notebook multiple users login

Tags: ipython

IPython HTML notebook looks incredible!
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html

I'm thinking of using it for our computational/numerics classes, but can't find an documented way to provide login for multiple users (Only a password protected - even no username). It seems odd to provide only password protected environment. Ideally, i would want multiple usernames (+ password) with unique home directory for each user for storing scripts.

If someone is familiar with IPythone HTML notebook source code: Can that be done in an easy way? Or with couple of day work on IPython source code?

Thanks!

Comment: I found useful informations on http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/ipython-html-notebook-server-on-dotcloud-td4987417.html   Making the notebook server multiuser aware.  _This is definitely on
our radar and we are trying to get this work funded through academic
grants.  We are at the early stages of the planning of this._  I need some kind of hack. Somehow to wrap IPython HTML notebook page into another which requires login?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  I am interested in a similar thing.  Maybe some collaboration is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a solution, folks from Stanford University found rather simple solution:
https://github.com/cni/ipython-hydra

Answer (score 2):

The current solution for this is [jupyterhub](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub).